# How can I pass a Javascript string to HTML and have mathjax render the math?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, mathjax, flippant

I'm using flippant.css/js and isotope.js [to make flashcards for my algebra students](http://timbusken.com/flashcards/exponent-props.html).

But I can't get mathjax to render the HTML to math on the backside of a flashcard. [Here is my url](http://timbusken.com/flashcards/exponent-props.html)
and my code snippet that passes the string to html. Can anyone see what the fix is?

```
 var front1 = document.getElementById('card1')
        , back_content1 = '<h2>\\\(a^{n+m}\\\)</h2><button id="closeCard1">&laquo; Back</button>'
        , back1;

document.getElementById("flipCard1").addEventListener('tap',function(e){
        back1 = flippant.flip(front1, back_content1);
        document.getElementById("closeCard1").addEventListener('tap',function(e){
             back1 = back1.close();
        })
    })     
document.getElementById("flipCard1").addEventListener('click',function(e){
        back1 = flippant.flip(front1, back_content1);
        document.getElementById("closeCard1").addEventListener('click',function(e){
            back1 = back1.close();
        })
    })
```

Comment: I visited your site, and can see you found the problem. It is a nice idea and well-executed. One improvement: It would be better if the card stayed at the same place, when it flips.